# How to show the json element into some html element in a modal's bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I use codeigniter to develop my app, and now I want to manipulate some data using ajax in jquery. How to show the json element into some html element in a modal's bootstrap ?,
So This is the html and jquery code  :

```
<td  class="center">
    <a class="btn btn-info" id="btn-edit" name="edit" req_id="<?php echo $data['code_office'] . '/' . $data['code_departement'] . '/' . date('m', strtotime($data['month'])) . '/' . $data['id_request']; ?>">
        <i class="halflings-icon white edit"></i>
     </a>

 $(".btn-info").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                var idStr = $this.attr("req_id");
                var idText = idStr.split("/").pop(); //get id ex: 002
                console.log(idText); // for checking get id

                /*I use ajax to get data from mytable*/
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url() . 'control_closing/getDetailOfRequest/'?>',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { id : idText},
                    success: function(obj){                            
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Controller :

```
    public function getDetailOfRequest(){
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $row = $this->model_request->getDetailOfRequest($id);
      echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Model :

```
public function getDetailOfRequest($id){
    $this->db->select('kindOfRequest, Description');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_requestfix', array('id_request'=> $id));

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

I use firebug to check it. In firebug, I got this

```
[{"kindOfRequest":"Login, Printer, Monitor","Description":"keep calm and study hard"}]
```

My question is : kindofrequest above it would be generated into chekboxes which is the element would be marked as 'selected' and the other would be not checked. The 'Description' it would be into a textbox in modal's bootstrap. How can I make it ?
I think in ajax success, I can make it. Any suggestion ?

This is the modal bootstrap :

```
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="controls" id="chekboxes">               
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td><label class="control-label">Kind Of Complaint :</label></td>
            <td><div class="control-group">

                 <div class="controls" id="chekboxes">
                  <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" /> Login </label>
                  <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Printer" value="Printer"/> Printer </label>
                  <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Monitor" value="Monitor"/> Monitor</label>
                  <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Computer" value="Computer"/> Computer</label>
                  <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Network" value="Network"/> Network</label>
                   <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Other" value="Other" /> Other</label> 
                   </div>
                 </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td valign="top"><label class="control-label">Description :</label></td>
            <td><div class="control-group ">
                 <div class="controls">
                   <textarea class="cleditor" name="keluhan" id="modalkeluhan " rows="3"></textarea>
                 </div>
                  </div>
            </td>
           </tr>
           </tbody>
          </table>

        </div>                    
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax :

```
success: function(obj)
{   
    obj = jQuery.parseJSON(obj);
    var kor = obj.kindOfRequest.split(",")

    for (var k in kor ) 
    {
        $('input[type=checkbox][value='+kor[k]+']').prop('checked', true);    
    }

    $('#modalkeluhan').val(obj.Description); 

    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

For the record. I do almost the same thing on one of my projects. Here is how it works :

Model :

```
 return $query->row(); //return an object
```

Controller :

```
$a = $this->my_model->myfunction();
echo json_encode($a);
```

Ajax :

```
var post_array = { "id_product" : theval };
$.post(siteUrl + "/mycontrolle/myfunction", post_array,
    function(data)
    {
        data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

        line = $("div#productline");
        line.find(".fulldesingation").text(data.full_designation);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I got this error : TypeError: obj.kindOfRequest is undefined

Comment: I got this : [{"kindOfRequest":"Login, Printer, Monitor","Description":"keep calm and study hard"}]

Comment: I dont know, why it still not working, Perhaps, U can give me tips how to get element of array like myobj.kindOfRequest ? So, in console.log will viewing "Login, Printer, Monitor" ...

Comment: Well, JSON is great for that, if you want something just go for obj.something. In our case console.log(obj.kindOfRequest ) should be enough. but obviously there is something else.

Comment: Let's try something else, can you change result_array() to result() in your model and show me what console.log(obj) gives you ?

Comment: I try this :  console.log(myobj.kindOfRequest); 
It gives me : undefined .
OMG

Comment: same ? same console.log(obj) ?

Comment: Yes, console.log(obj) ===> [Object { kindOfRequest="Login, Printer, Monitor", Description="keep calm and study hard""}]

Comment: Nop it's not the same. See the "Object" at the begiing ?
You should be able to do obj.kindOfRequest now right ? Also, I edited my answer with the code I personnaly use and know is bulletproof :)

Comment: It's an object inside an array.  `var thing = obj[0].kindOfRequest;`

Comment: @James Ok, now I feel ashamed. Thx :) So Fadly Dzil  you can use James's solution or return ->row() in your model to get rid of the array.

Comment: New problem is raise, the modal's bootstrap is not take effect ... ?

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(obj) {  
   var kor = obj.kindOfRequest.split(",");

   for (var i = 0; i < kor.length; i++) {
      // kor[i] fetches the list of kindOfRequest. e.g. kor[1] = Login
      // You can make the value and class a same name and if the value from json matched the class name of checkbox then check it using `prop` 
   }

   $('#modalkeluhan').val(obj.Description); 
   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

```
<div class="controls" id="chekboxes">
    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Login" value="Login" class="Login" /> Login </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Printer" value="Printer" class="Printer"/> Printer </label>
    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Monitor" value="Monitor" class="Monitor"/> Monitor</label>
    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Computer" value="Computer" class="Computer"/> Computer</label>
    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Network" value="Network" class="Network"/> Network</label>
    <label class="checkbox inline"><input type="checkbox" name="request[]" id="Other" value="Other" class="Other" /> Other</label> 
</div>
```